# AngularFire V1.2 $firebaseArray() $loaded() only called once

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire, angular-promise

I am using AngularFire and promises on arrays (`$loaded()` on `firebaseArray()`).

Currently, I'm using the following code:

**Problem**: I go to page1, the data is loaded and all fine. Go to page 2 and come back to page1. Now the `$loaded()` doesn't work until I do a full page refresh. How do I fix this problem?

```
app.factory('Items', ['FBURL', '$firebaseArray', function(FBURL, $firebaseArray) {
    return {
      ofCategory: function(catId){
        var ref = new Firebase(FBURL);
        var refSearch = new Firebase.util.NormalizedCollection(...).select(...).ref(); 
        var allItems= refSearch.orderByChild(...);
        return $firebaseArray(allItems);
      }
    }; 
}]);
```

Page1:

```
function readData() { 
  if($scope.Items) { 
     $scope.Items.$destroy();
     $scope.Items= null;
  }   
  $scope.Items = Items.ofCategory($routeParams.id);
  $scope.Items.$loaded().then(function(itm) {
        ...
  });
}
```

Page2:

```
$scope.Items= Items.ofCategory($routeParams.id);
```

The Firebase documentation<sup>[1](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/guide/introduction-to-angularfire.md#handling-asynchronous-operations)</sup> says: "`$loaded()` returns a promise which resolves after the initial records have been downloaded from our database. This is **only called once** and should be used with care", and that is probably what I get here.

**What I've tried**: As shown, in my `readData()` function on Page1, I destroy the `$scope.Items` variable before any new load. But it doesn't seem to be doing anything. AFAIU, `$loaded()` is working on `firebaseArray()`, so destroying the `$scope` array might not help much. So, what else should I do to make this work without needing to fully refresh the page?

Comment: What do you mean when you say, "`$loaded()` doesn't work"? Is there an error message? Does `.catch` return an error? Describe the erroneous behavior.

Comment: @georgeawg, thanks. There is no error. `.catch` does not catch any error. It's just that the code doesn't go inside the `$loaded()` after it has been loaded once and that's probably what it is supposed to do. One might also ask "why don't you just stick with the loaded array and why do you need as second call?" and my response would be that because I don't just simply use the loaded array. I do some stuff with the items, so I need to call the '$loaded()' to have the data ready before doing calculations.

Comment: See [Github commit: Fire loaded event even if data was loaded from cache, fixes #194](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/commit/96b28d103dad615098f9c6e1651f5336ecce4298). Issue #194: [Multiple $firebase instances attached to same path do not trigger `loaded` event](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/issues/194).

Comment: How is this possible? this GitHub commit is for Jan2014. I'm using AngularFire v1.2.0 which was released in Mar2016! The releases after that will not work with Firebase 2.x (my current version)

Comment: It looks like that the second time, it doesn't actually trigger the `loaded()`, so the `then()` part doesn't get called..

Answer (score 1):

I have heard that AngularFire should be avoided and this looks like a good reason.

Use the firebase API directly:

```
app.factory('FbItems', ['FBURL', '$q', function(FBURL, $q) {
    return {
      ofCategory: function(catId){
        var ref = new Firebase(FBURL);
        var refSearch = new Firebase.util.NormalizedCollection(...).select(...).ref(); 
        var allItems= refSearch.orderByChild(...);
        var promise = allItems.once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
            return snapshot.val();
        });
        return $q.when(promise);
      }
    }; 
}]);
```

It is important to convert the ES6 promise to an AngularJS $q promise with [`$q.when`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#when). Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc.

Usage:

```
function readData() { 
  promise = FbItems.ofCategory($routeParams.id);
  promise.then(function(items) {
      $scope.Items = items;
  }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
  });
}
```

Comment: thanks @georgeawg. this line `var promise = allItems.once().then(function(snapshot) {` gives me a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined` error. Can you also elaborate why we have 2 returns? when do we get to `return $q.when(promise);` if we already return?

Comment: Updated answer. It should be `.once('value')`.

Comment: thank you. I'll wait a bit to see if someone from Firebase can comment on my original code? If not, I shall raise that as an issue for AngularFire (although they mention that using `$loaded()` is generally a bad practice)

Comment: I tried this solution today, but it didn't work, getting the error (`allItems.once(...).then is not a function`). Could be because I'm using the `NormalizedCollection`?